# How to increase validation accuracy on a specific dataset?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to train a DNN with keras. I have a dataset with 4000 rows of data that each belong to a programmer.

The features are: skills, study time, certificates, number of co-workers, ... and there is a salary column that is my target.

I tried to train several DNN and the accuracy gets near 95 and above in most of the cases but validation accuracy is a trouble.The validation accuracy never exceeds ~40% and I believe that is a problem for my project accuracy.

To increase validation accuracy and reduce overfiting I tried to reduce the input size by cutting off some irrelevant features (from 400 to ~50). Also, I trained some DNN with dropout layers. These actions increased the validation accuracy a bit (maximum: 47%) but I'm not satisfied by the result.

The input is a numpy array and it looks like this:

`array([4, 1, 3, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0])`

the first five indices are: 'age', 'work_state', 'education', 'co_workers', 'experience' and these are encoded data.

the rest is: 'project_language', 'work_field', 'workplace_type' and they have multiple values so i encoded them like that. (hot-spot categorical?)

The target shape is '(4000, 8)' and it's a one-hot-categorical vector:

`array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0])`

So I trained about 144 DNNs and the best result was 47% validation accuracy:

```
activation_list = ['relu', 'tanh']
loss_list = ['categorical_crossentropy']
optimizer_list = ['rmsprop', 'adam']
drop_list = [None, 0.25, 0.5]
nn_arc_list = [
    (32, 16),
    (128, 64),
    (256, 64),
    (128, 32, 16),
    (1024, 256, 64),
    (1024, 256, 64, 16),
    (1024, 512, 128, 64),
    (2048, 1024, 512, 256, 128, 64, 32, 16),
    (4096, 1024, 256, 128, 64, 32, 16, 8),
    (128, 64, 32, 32, 16, 16, 8),
    (1024, 1024, 512, 512, 64, 64),
    (128, 128, 64, 64, 64, 64),
    ]
```

what can I do to increase the validation accuracy?

my train.py code:

```
# load training and test data
with open('./ml_dataset.pickle', 'rb') as my_file:
    (train_x, train_y), (test_x, test_y) = pickle.load(my_file)


def create_nn(neurons_architecture, activation, optimizer, loss, dropout):
    model = Sequential()
    input_shape = train_x.shape[1:]

    # add first layer. this layer is added separately because we want to define
    # input shape in it
    model.add(Dense(neurons_architecture[0],
                    activation=activation,
                    input_shape=input_shape))
    if dropout is not None:
        model.add(Dropout(dropout))

    # add the rest of layers
    for neurons in neurons_architecture[1:]:
        model.add(Dense(neurons, activation=activation))
        if dropout is not None:
            model.add(Dropout(dropout))

    # add the last layer and compile
    model.add(Dense(8, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
                  loss=loss,
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model


activation_list = ['relu', 'tanh']
loss_list = ['categorical_crossentropy']
optimizer_list = ['rmsprop', 'adam']
drop_list = [None, 0.25, 0.5]
nn_arc_list = [
    (32, 16),
    (128, 64),
    (256, 64),
    (128, 32, 16),
    (1024, 256, 64),
    (1024, 256, 64, 16),
    (1024, 512, 128, 64),
    (2048, 1024, 512, 256, 128, 64, 32, 16),
    (4096, 1024, 256, 128, 64, 32, 16, 8),
    (128, 64, 32, 32, 16, 16, 8),
    (1024, 1024, 512, 512, 64, 64),
    (128, 128, 64, 64, 64, 64),
    ]

all_states = product(nn_arc_list, activation_list, loss_list, optimizer_list, drop_list)

for state in all_states:
    neuron_arc, activation, loss = state[0], state[1], state[2]
    optimizer, dropout = state[3], state[4]
    model = create_nn(neuron_arc, activation, optimizer, loss, dropout)

    history = model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=number_of_epochs,
                        batch_size=256, validation_split=0.2,
                        shuffle=True, verbose=False)

    # I removed the code the generates file_name to reduce the code size
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as my_file:
        pickle.dump(history, my_file)
```

Comment: Normalize your input features. Maybe batch normalization also. Number of samples is small compared with the amount of features (perhaps you can delete more). With such dataset, you can first try logistic regression, SVM, ...

Comment: You can also try different values for validation split and batch size

Comment: @victor I don't think I can normalize my data. there are 5 categorical feature and the rest is a bunch of yes and no. And you are right about the dataset size, yet it's all I have. thanks for your suggestion and your time.

Comment: @victor hmmm, I have 400 test data. I think I can use them as validation instead and use the whole 4000 data train the DNN. Is this OK?

Comment: For small datasets is better a higher train/test size ratio. 10% fine

Comment: I suggest analyzing linear correlations between each input feature with the outcome variable. Then you can select the top 5-10 features (You can use pandas DataFrame.corr method)